# Unity3d Gyroscope look around

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I am trying to build a solar system exploration app through unity. I have the environment set up, and now all I need is the ability to look around (via tilting and moving the phone itself, which is android) smoothly. I have the ability to look around, but if I do a complete 180, it seems to invert the physical orientation of the phone with the visual movements in game, e.g. if I have turn 180 degrees, if I tilt the phone down it shifts my vision in game to the right, up results in visual shift to the left. Here is the code I have thus far:

```
#pragma strict

private var quatMult : Quaternion;
private var quatMap : Quaternion;

function Start () {
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
}

function Update () {

#if UNITY_ANDROID
    quatMap = Input.gyro.attitude;
#endif

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0) * quatMap * Quaternion(0,0,1,0) /*quatMult*/;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the gyro rotation instead of just doing `transform.localRotation = Input.gyro.attitude;`?

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you're looking for: https://gist.github.com/chanibal/baf46307c4fee3c699d5. Just drag it to the camera and it should work.

You might want to remove the reset on touch part (`Input.touchCount > 0` in `Update`) and debug information (the `OnGui` method).

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses. My team and I actually decided to use our school's Oculus Rift for our project instead of a smartphone/google cardboard. So, this brings me to my next question: We have the OVRPlayerController and everything working on the Oculus paired with a logitech controller. So, when moving forward on the joystick, and turning your head and the rift to the left, the player will move left; the same for going right. The problem is it doesn't work for vertical movements. So, if I'm holding forward on the controller and look up, it want to fly upward. Is this possible?

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific with your setup - what is the Logitech controller (gamepad?) and what should be it's relation to the Oculus Rift? This will probably be outside the scope of this question. I so, ask it in another question (post link here), and (if I helped), accept this answer.